# How to synchronize Solr import processes?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, indexing, solrj

How can I synchronize Solr delta import processes? Several threads run delta import. If during import run one more import then the second run will be ignored and data will not updated.

My purpose is to make waiting the second to finish the first delta import.

Delta import runs via HTTP, so I don't know how to check when it's finished.

Uses: Solr 4.0, SolrJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can poll the status of the dataimporthandler with the url `http://host:port/solr/dataimport?command=status` or even without any command since status is the default one. That way you get back some details about the dataimport process and you can find out if it is still in progress or not. Have a look at the [available commands](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Commands).

Comment: yep, it's a good idea. thanks for answer. but i have several dataimport which updates the sama index. so I hope to get lock in someway. Lucene creates write.lock but how to ger it I don't know.

Comment: I think you can check at a higher level. You should run only one import process for each index. Is this reasonable for you? If yes, just check the dataimport status of your core, if it says busy it means it's running. When it's idle you can run a new import.

Comment: But I  have three separate Data Import update single index. So to check if some import is working I must send three requests to SOlr server. I would prefer check once

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you could do something with this

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#EventListeners

If you can use that to maintain a "importInProgress" boolean flag, you could probably extend or wrap the data import handler class in your own code and return a custom response of your own to indicate that the system is busy. This way you could never have two imports processing. Polling for status as per javanna sounds like it will be subject to race conditions.

Comment: But if you find the documentation for EventListeners it says Event listener for DataImportHandler This API is experimental and subject to change

Comment: That's a bit disappointing. Perhaps mail the solr dev list to see how likely they think it is to change. These sorts of documentation warnings sometimes are stale.

Comment: I got following reply in solr mail chain ....There are various options for this: 1. Synchronise externally between the threads that launch the delta-import processes. It is unclear as to why you need multiple threads. 2. Look at wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler to see how one could check the status of a data import at /solr/dataimport?command=status 3. Do delta imports into separate cores, merge, and swap.